Ola maps integration in Flutter
So I am working on a similar project like ola for the tier 3 cities and i see that ola maps are free but Ola Maps only provide android sdk, and does not support flutter for now, how do I implement the android sdk in my flutter project, should I use the navigation sdk or the routing and places API, if anyone can provide me code snippet. Thankyou in advance
I did try connecting with the ola maps technical team and guess what they do not support for the flutter now, I am hoping if anyone has an alternative idea for this.

You need to write your own native code and connect it using method channel in your flutter application

I am also looking for same.

Hello I have started creating Ola Map SDK plugin for Flutter. Just have a look at it. Will be completing this in some time. For now, most of the functionality are available for Android only. In IOS the view is only done.
Ola Map Flutter Plugin

getting this issue IN FLUTTER after adding olamaps
[HTTP] Request with response = 401: No additional information
D/Mbgl-HttpRequest(28729): [HTTP] This request was cancelled (https://api.olamaps.io/tiles/vector/v1/styles/default-light-standard/style.json). This is expected for tiles that were being prefetched but are no longer needed for the map to render.
E/Mbgl    (28729): {.demoolamaps002}[Setup]: loading style failed: HTTP status code 401
E/OlaMapFlutterPlugin(28729): Map initialization error: loading style failed: HTTP status code 401
D/Mbgl-HttpRequest(28729): [HTTP] Request with response = 401: No additional information

